# Flash CM on encrypted phone running stock Android

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, encryption

My Nexus 4 is currently running an encrypted Android 5.1.
Now I want to flash CM12. Can CM access my Data after flashing or do I need to remove the encryption before flashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you will most likely lose all your data, because:

- You have to unlock your bootloader when you install a third party ROM. Unlocking the bootloader will erase all your data.
- The new installation *might* not be able to decrypt your data.
- Even if it would work, it is still not recommended to keep all the data when installing a different version or make of a ROM.

You should make a backup of all your data, then format your phone.

Comment: Ah true.. I forgot that I need to unlock the bootloader.. But what if I'm already running a custom rom? What if I wanted to change from CM to Paranoid?

Comment: full-disk encryption has the same implementation across all Android flavors, AFAIK. there's really no reason that distributors would change that.

Comment: It's usually best to reduce the number of variables as much as possible before flashing, including un-encrypting. And you can't have too many backups!